# Can't get parameters from url with Redux ownProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

### So I'm having an error message - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

**AddOrUpdateProduct.js**

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const productId = ownProps.match.params.productId;
    const product =
        productId && state.productListReducer.length > 0
            ? getProductById(state.productListReducer, productId)
            : {}
    return {
        product: product,
        products: state.productListReducer,
        categories: state.categoryListReducer
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="/product" exact element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="/saveproduct/:productId" element={<AddOrUpdateProduct />} />
          <Route path="/cart" exact element={<CartDetail />} />
        </Routes>
```

**I'm trying to get the productid in the url with 'ownProps.match.params.productId'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

In `react-router-dom@6` there are no longer route props. If you need to access the `productId` route param then you will need to create a Higher Order Component to access the route props and inject them as props into your class component.

## Solution

Create a custom `withRouter` component:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const withRouter = Component => props => {
  const params = useParams();
  return <Component {...props} params={params} />;
}
```

Wrap and decorate the `AddOrUpdateProduct` component so it has the `params` injected as a prop.

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const productId = ownProps.params.productId;
  const product =
    productId && state.productListReducer.length > 0
      ? getProductById(state.productListReducer, productId)
      : {};

  return {
    product,
    products: state.productListReducer,
    categories: state.categoryListReducer
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(AddOrUpdateProduct));
```

Answer (score 0):

No react expert here but I think you need to use `withRoute` when exporting the component, something like this

```
export default withRouter(AddOrUpdateProduct);
```

Comment: i tried it didn't work